# Connection to two different databases in single class

Tags: java, oracle, hadoop

I need to connect to  two different database from my code. First is Hive database and another one is Oracle. For this purpose I need to load two different drivers one for Hive and another for Oracle. Here is what I did:

```
        Class.forName("org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver Found");
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:hive2://10.8.219.36:10000/default", "lab", "lab");
        System.out.println("Connection established");

        System.out.println("------------------");

        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        System.out.println("Driver Found");
        Connection connection1 = DriverManager.getConnection(
                "jdbc:oracle:thin:@97.253.16.117:1521:NATTDB11",
                "CDR_LOADER", "CDR_LOADER");
        System.out.println("Connection established");
```

and when I am running the above code, this is what is got error:

```
Driver Found
Connection established
------------------
Driver Found
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Bad URL format
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.Utils.parseURL(Utils.java:185)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveConnection.<init>(HiveConnection.java:84)
at org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver.connect(HiveDriver.java:104)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at Demo.main(Demo.java:17)
```

How do I do this? Thank you in advance.

Comment: you did it correct way. According to error it should be wrong url for the Oracle DB. Try to connect manually to the database using that url and credential.

Comment: Might be a problem with connection string. Please check it once again.

Comment: Try this connection string format: `jdbc:oracle:thin:@//HOSTNAME:PORT/SERVICENAME` - `"jdbc:oracle:thin:@//97.253.16.117:1521/NATTDB11"`

Answer (score 1):

Try to explicitly register both drivers using:

```
DriverManager.registerDriver (new oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver());
DriverManager.registerDriver (new org.apache.hive.jdbc.HiveDriver());
```

Then test both Connection types.